# Switch Statement implementation not providing expected behavior

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I am developing a quizz application in vanilla JavaScript and in the interest of best practices, I want to ensure I follow the D.R.Y. principle.

I have five questions that I need to check answers for.

As a result, instead of using `if` statements five times, I thought I could implement a `switch` statement like so:

callback.js:

```
function submitAnswers() {
  var total = 5;
  var score = 0;
  // Get User Input
  var q1 = document.forms['quizForm']['q1'].value;
  var q2 = document.forms['quizForm']['q2'].value;
  var q3 = document.forms['quizForm']['q3'].value;
  var q4 = document.forms['quizForm']['q4'].value;
  var q5 = document.forms['quizForm']['q5'].value;

  // Validation
  for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    if (eval('q'+i) == null || eval('q'+i) == '') {
      alert('You missed question '+ i);
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Set Correct Answers
  var answers = ["d","b","c","a","b"];

  // Check answers
  switch (answers) {
    case q1 == answers[0]:
      score++;
      break;
    case q2 == answers[1]:
      score++;
      break;
    case q3 == answers[2]:
      score++;
      break;
    case q4 == answers[3]:
      score++;
      break;
    case q5 == answers[4]:
      score++;
      break;
  }

  alert('You scored '+score+' out of ' +total);
}
```

This is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/callback.js"></script>
        <title>Quiz About the Wonderful World of Fungi</title>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="container">
                <header>
                    <h1>Quiz About the Wonderful World of Fungi</h1>
                    <p>Test your knowledge</p>
                </header>
                <section>
                        <div id="results"></div>
                        <form class="myForm" name="quizForm" onSubmit="return submitAnswers()">
                            <h3>1. Roughly how many species of organisms of the kingdom of Fungi have been identified, so far?</h3>
                            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a">a. 2 Million<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b">b. 37,000<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c">c. 58,000<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d">d. 73,000<br>

                            <h3>2. The process of specifically using mushrooms to break down toxic chemicals and sequester heavy metals is known as:</h3>
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a">a. Bioremediation<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b">b. Mushremediation<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c">c. Mycoremediation<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d">d. Chitinremediation<br>

                            <h3>3. The above-ground part of the mushroom that  we typically associate with a mushroom is only a small part of the whole organism,
                                            as most of it is underground. What is the primary role of this part of the  whole organism?</h3>
                            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a">a. Nutrient Absorptionn<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b">b. Protection<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c">c. Sexual Reproduction<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d">d. Oxygen Absorption<br>

                            <h3>4. What Is the primary role of a mushroom’s underground mycelium?</h3>
                            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a">a. Nutrient Absorption<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b">b. Anchoring<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4c">c. Asexual Reproduction<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" id="q4d">d. Protection<br>

                            <h3>5. The largest living organism on earth is thought to be a mushroom (the honey fungus) and it is estimated to be what distance across?</h3>
                            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a">a. 0.5 mile<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b">b. 2.4 miles<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5c">c. 8 miles<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5d">d. 0.7 mile<br>
                            <br><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit Answers">
                        </form>

                </section>
                <footer>
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017, All Rights Reserved</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Upon testing this, I continued to get an alert saying I have 0 out of 5 correct, even when choosing the correct answers.

Is the `switch` statement not the best solution here? Am I applying it wrong?

Comment: Please read a book about Javascript and how to use `switch` statements

Comment: switch compares the condition `switch (condition)` againts each `case`

Comment: You are indeed, a switch statements condition is what it's comparing against for each case. Since you comparing several separate values it doesn't make sense to use a switch here. There are better ways to do this, just as using a loop and do `if` comparisons inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `switch` value must match one of the case expressions. `answers` will never match `q1 == answers[0]` or similar. If you changed it to `switch (true)` the `switch` would work, but you'd still only be checking *one* answer, not all five (and it's not a very good use of `switch`).

If you use five different `qX` variables, you'll need five different `if` statements. But that's not what you should do. Instead, see `***` comments:

```
function submitAnswers() {
  var total = 5;
  var score = 0;
  var i; // *** Note we declare `i` so it's not an implicit global
  // Get User Input
  // *** ...as an array
  var responses = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    responses.push(document.forms['quizForm']['q' + i].value);
  };

  // Set Correct Answers
  // *** Moved
  var answers = ["d","b","c","a","b"];

  // Validation and check answers both at once
  for (i = 0; i < responses.length; ++i) {
    // *** `value` is never `null`, we can just use ! here
    if (!responses[i]) {
      alert('You missed question '+ i);
      return false;
    }
    // *** Check response
    if (response[i] == answers[i]) {
      ++score;
    }
  }

  alert('You scored '+score+' out of ' +total);
}
```

A couple of notes:

- It's important to declare your variables (you didn't declare `i`). If you don't, in loose mode you can end up creating global variables by mistake, which can be quite difficult to debug. More (in a post on my anemic little blog)*: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)
- Any time you reach for `eval` to form a variable name like `q1`, `q2`, etc., you probably want an array instead. There are valid use cases for `eval`, but they're very few and far between.

Comment: T.J., thank you for your help. I will study the notes you wrote here and your blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method. Form an array with all chosen answers and compare iteratively using `Array#every`

```
var correctanswers = ["d","b","c","a","b"];
var choosenanswers = [q1,q2,q3,q4,q5];
var isallcorrect = choosenanswers.every(function(item,index){
    return item == correctanswers[index];
});
console.log(isallcorrect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable function for this instead of switch statement, and use for loop to check every target value;

```js
// Answers
var answers = ["a", "b", "c"]

// Correct increments
var correct = 0;

// checkAnswer Function
var checkAnswer = function(question, answer) {
  if (question !== answer) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Notice length - 1, because we have button element there
  /**
    * If you want to declare variable for each inputs, change 
    * e.target.length and e.target[i].value to your arrays of q/a 
    */
  for (var i = 0; i < e.target.length - 1; i++) {
    if (checkAnswer(e.target[i].value, answers[i]) === false) {
      alert('False answer')
      // Right answer function here
    } else {
      correct++
      alert('Right answer!')
      // False answer here
    }
  }
  alert('Your answer is ' + correct + ' correct out of ' + (e.target.length - 1) + ' questions!');
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="q1">
  <input type="text" id="q2">
  <input type="text" id="q3">
  <button type="submit">Submit answer</button>
</form>
```